# Get Current Active Tab through JS.

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display the current tab as active in BOOTSTRAP.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">               
    <!-- Default tab -->
    <li class="active"><a href="#elemLower_tab" data-toggle="tab">Elementary Lower</a></li>
    <li><a href="#elemAdvance_tab" data-toggle="tab">Elementary Advance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#secondary_tab" data-toggle="tab">Secondary</a></li>               
</ul>
```

I want to get the current tab active through jQuery? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try

```
$('.nav-tabs .active').text()
```

Comment: I didn't know that it changes class when the tab is clicked. This really what I need. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to get the destination id, then use $('.nav-tabs .active > a').attr('href')

Answer (score 0):

Use this JS Code.

```
$(function(){
var url = window.location.pathname,
urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$");
$('ul.nav-tabs li a').each(function(){
if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
$(this).addClass('active');
}
});
});
```

Use CSS:Attach Active class to

```
ul.nav-tabs a.active{color:#000;}
```

Comment: He doesn't want to set the class, he wants to get the element with the active class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run JavaScript code whenever the current tab changes, see `show` and `shown` events in the [tabs plugin documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).